# Bash scriptint Let statement error

Tags: bash

I am making a simple bash script but it seems that i'm having trouble using the let statement... getting some errors... Some help?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter the first number:"
read var1
echo -n "Enter the second nubmber:"
read var2
declare -i var3
echo ----------------------
echo "$var1 + $var2 = $(($var1+$var2))"
let res=$var1*$var2
echo "$var1 * $var2"=$res"
```

Comment: What are the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the following errors:

```
./1.sh: line 10: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./1.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

They're caused by the last character of the script: `"` which starts a new string literal that never ends.

Comment: oh my bad :D... anyway is there syntax that i should use when i write my let statement? I mean something with the quotes?

Comment: I usually use the `(( res = var1 * var2 ))` syntax.

Comment: bash is a strange language... actually strange syntax lol, so many variations